# Is there a way of allowing sub classes to override only -some- parents abstracts methods

Tags: c#, inheritance

I understand that the title may not make sense, but the below should explain my predicament.

So I'm making a user interface for my MonoGame game. I have an abstract class `Clickable` which contains some basic methods that are called when certain actions happen (And a few other things i have left out for clarity's sake):

```
abstract public class Clickable
{
    public abstract void OnClick(Vector2 pos, MouseButton button);

    public abstract void OnHover(Vector2 pos);

    public abstract void OnUnHover(Vector2 pos);

    public abstract void OnHold(Vector2 pos, MouseButton button);

    public abstract void OnRelease(Vector2 pos, MouseButton button);
}
```

Each of these methods can be called by my `ControlManager`, which cycles through a list of `Clickable`'s to see if any of the above methods currently apply.

I then have a class which inherits from `Clickable` called `Control` (again stripped down):

```
abstract public class Control : Clickable
{
    public abstract void DrawBackground(SpriteBatch sb, GameTime gt);

    public abstract void DrawMiddleground(SpriteBatch sb, GameTime gt);

    public abstract void DrawForeground(SpriteBatch sb, GameTime gt);
}
```

So, my user controls inherit from this. My issue is, is that in order to have a compile-able class, i HAVE to to override all of these abstract methods.

Take the not-finished `TextBox` class:

```
class TextBox : Control
{
    Typeable typeable;

    public TextBox(Vector2 position, int width, int height, string text, SpriteFont font, Control alignedTo, Dictionary<String, Texture2D> images) :
        base(position, width, height, alignedTo, images)
    {
        typeable = new Typeable(text, font, position);
    }

    public override void OnClick(Vector2 position, MouseButton button)
    {
        //Cursor functions will go here
    }

    public override void OnHold(Vector2 pos, MouseButton button)
    {

    }

    public override void OnHover(Vector2 pos)
    {

    }

    public override void OnRelease(Vector2 pos, MouseButton button)
    {

    }

    public override void OnUnHover(Vector2 pos)
    {

    }

    public override void DrawBackground(SpriteBatch sb, GameTime gt)
    {

    }

    public override void DrawMiddleground(SpriteBatch sb, GameTime gt)
    {
        //draw textbox background
    }

    public override void DrawForeground(SpriteBatch sb, GameTime gt)
    {
        //draw textbox text
    }
}
```

As you can see, (where the comments are), i will only be using some of the methods that i am forced to declare.

Is there a way that i can have the base methods in my abstract classes and not *have* to override, (just have the option to)? Bare in mind a class like `TextBox` that will not implement the `OnHold` method, will still have it called by the `ControlManager` if a user holds the mouse button down on the control.

Comment: You probably should break out your design further. Maybe instead of one large base class, you need multiple smaller interfaces, and then each class only implement the interface(s) it needs. Or maybe you go a different route and make your base class methods virtual, and then derived classes only override what's necessary. But if it were me, I'd revisit the design.

Comment: Definetly revisit the design, because you are breaking the segregation principle (quote): "Each interface should have a specific purpose. You shouldn’t be forced to implement an interface when your object doesn’t share that purpose. By extrapolation, the larger the interface, the more likely it includes methods that not all implementers can achieve. That’s the essence of the Interface Segregation Principle."

Comment: I think i will definitely split the Clickable class out to an Interface after hearing everyone's suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end, the answer to your question is **no**. For a class to be instantiated (instantiatable?), it has to override every abstract method (or inherit from a class that implements the methods it doesn not implement).

To make this "optional" just mark them as `virtual` instead of `abstract`, and provide the default (empty) implementation in the base class. Only use `abstract` when you actually want all derived classes to implement the method.

A method marked `virtual` must have an implementation, even if its empty:

```
public virtual void MyFunc()
{
}
```

Is valid. This will be called unless the derived object has:

```
public override void MyFunc()
{
   //Some implementation
}
```

Basically, **You can't have method declarations without a method body *somewhere* in C#.**

Comment: I had tried to use virtual but i did not make a method body (Didn't know i had to) and so was encountering errors. I've come over from Java where overriding methods is a lot simpler, do i have to provide a piece of code to run the base class? Or is this just VisualStudio suggesting it?

Comment: If a method is marked `virtual` it has to have an implementation

Comment: Yes, it does, the last sentence pretty much sums it up. All solved by changing the abstracts to virtual and replacing my ; with {}

Comment: @LexWebb, Great! I tried to emphasize that statement since it was so helpful. Glad I was able to be of assistance.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way that i can have the base methods in my abstract classes and not have to override, (just have the option to)?

No.

> Bear in mind a class like TextBox that will not implement the OnHold method, will still have it called by the ControlManager if a user holds the mouse button down on the control.

You want to have too much in your base class. Not all controls are clickable, so the click methods should not be in the base class. What you seem to be needing is multiple inheritance.

You can do this using interfaces:

```
public class Button: Control, IClickable[, IScrollable[, I...]]
{
    public void OnClick(Vector2 position, MouseButton button)
    {
        // implements IClickable 
    }    
}
```

You won't have to repeat much code between controls able to receive clicks, as you can also put the click handling methods in an `IClickHandler` and let that be implemented by a basic event handler.

Answer (score 1):

If there are methods which aren't 100% necassery, you can have them marked as `virtual` and provide a basic implementation, which might even be just an empty method. That way, you cab still override where they are deseriable, and where they're not they can just use the "base" implementation. You **absolutely cannot** not implement an `abstract` method.

Comment: Marking them as virtual wouldn't cause you to utilize the `base` keyword. Is there a reason you used the code markup for it?

Comment: Im sorry i dont understand what you mean

Comment: Using virtual means you just let the framework call the base class for you, you don't write `override void MyFunc() { base.MyFunc() }`. Thus I am curious if you intended to write "`base` implementation" or just "base implementation"

Comment: Oh, i ment base without the code markup. Didnt mean you *explicitly* have to call `base` :)